# Representation by exponentials of simply periodic complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am reading Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis* and he says that if $f$ is an entire function which has period $1$ (that is, $f(z)=f(z+1)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$), there exists a unique analytic function $F$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $$f(z) = F(e^{2\pi iz}).$$ I am trying to understand why that function exists.

Since $f(z)=f(z+n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $$f\left( \frac{1}{2\pi i} \log(e^{2\pi i z}) \right) = f\left( \frac{1}{2\pi i} (2\pi iz + 2\pi i n) \right) = f(z+n) = f(z).$$ Therefore, I guess that the correct choice of $F$ is $$F(w) = f\left( \frac{1}{2\pi i} \log(w) \right).$$ However, I don't know how to prove that this $F$ is well-defined, and is analytic.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2909424/42969

Answer (score 1):

You just proved that $F$ is well-defined (it desn't depend on the $2i\pi n$ term, that is it doesn't depend on the branch of $\log$) and it is obvious that it is analytic because locally *some* branch of $\log$ is analytic.